# Linear combination of normally distributed variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

We know that if $X \sim N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ then $a'X \sim N(a'\mu,a'\Sigma a)$ for and $a \in \mathbb{R}_p$. What I need to know is if the converse of this is also true. Can this be proved? Would appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Edit: Now I know this is true from what I have copied from Johnson's and Wichern's Applied multivariate statistical analysis. Only thing required now is the proof.

> **Result 4.2** If $X$ is distributed normally as $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ then any linear combination of variables $a'X = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + \cdots + a_pX_p$ is distributed as $N(a'\mu, a'\Sigma a)$. Also, if $a'X$ is distributed as $N(a'\mu, a'\Sigma a)$ for every $a$, then $X$ must be $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$.

Comment: What do you call "the converse of this"? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did if $aX$~$N(aμ,a′Σa)$ then $X$~$N_p(μ,Σ)$

Comment: If $a$ has a left-inverse this is trivially true, otherwise this is false. Here you seem to consider $a$ and $X$ vectors of size $p$ (in which case $aX$ and $a\mu$ should read $a'X$ and $a'\mu$), then there is no hope unless $p=1$ and $a\ne0$.

Comment: @Did Thanks for pointing it out I corrected my question

Comment: Then the converse cannot hold--if only for dimension reasons: unless $p=1$, one cannot deduce $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, of respective sizes $p$ and $\frac12p(p+1)$, from $a'\mu$ and $a'\Sigma a$, of respective sizes $1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Did I have a text book which says this is true which I found just nw. (Johnson and Wichern-applied multivariate statistical analysis).

Comment: @Did Please take a look at the latest edit I have made to the question.

Comment: ... **for every $a$** ... (Which is definitely not the question you asked here.)

Comment: @did how is it different?

Comment: How is a property holding for one specific `a` different from the same property holding for every `a`? Is this your question?

Comment: @did To be honest I think Donald has meant for each "$a$" in both cases. However, since this is true for every "$a$" there is no reason why it would be wrong for a specific "a" right?

Comment: @Heisenberg Once again, the OP first asked whether property $P(a)$ for some $a$ implies property $Q$, now they ask whether property $P(a)$ for every $a$ implies property $Q$. I mentioned that the former was hopeless and that the former and the latter are quite different (and I may add that the latter is true and textbook stuff).

Comment: A bounty of +50 for pure textbook stuff? Well... Hint: Characteristic functions *characterize* distributions.

Comment: You can find the proof as proposition 3.4.3 in this set of notes: http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/randomprocesses.html.

Answer (score 1):

(As [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) commented "Characteristic functions Characterize Distributions".) Assume that $a'X\sim N(a'\mu,a'\Sigma a)$ for every $a\in\mathbb{R}^p$. (Here $a'$ represents the transpose of the vector $a$). This is equivalent to the fact that the characteristic function $\Phi$ of $a'X$ is given by
$$
\Phi(t)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{ita'X}\right)=\exp\left(ita'\mu-\frac{1}{2} t^2a'\Sigma a\right)
$$
In particular, for $t=1$, and every $a\in\mathbb{R}^p$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i a'X}\right)=\exp\left(i a'\mu-\frac{1}{2}  a'\Sigma a\right)
$$
But this means that $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$.$\qquad\square$