# Linear Combination of variables from the exponential family

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, linear-transformations

As pointed out in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838509/linear-combination-of-normally-distributed-variables?rq=1), linear combinations of normal distributed variables are normal distributed:

> If $X$ is distributed normally as $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ then any linear combination of variables $a'X = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + \cdots + a_pX_p$ is distributed as $N(a'\mu, a'\Sigma a)$. Also, if $a'X$ is distributed as $N(a'\mu, a'\Sigma a)$ for every $a$, then $X$ must be $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$.

Can this result be generalized to broader classes of probability distributions as the exponential family?